# automatic launching of tomcat script in ec2

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat

i am trying to launch apahe tomcat automatically when the system boots in suse enterprise linux
 i have installed apache tomcat8 in suse enterprise linux
 i have attached the script in bash file
 i have edited the path in catalina also
 my 8080 port is working fine
 when i launch manually using sh startup.sh everything is working fine
 when i try to launch the server automatically its showing tomcat started 
 when i try to use in browser it will show error (page is not found)
 plz help out from this problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  It belongs on either the UNIX / Linux stackexchange site, or on the ServerFault.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.